# Can ggplot only plot x and y as isolated vectors?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I know this is too simple of a question but can `ggplot` (or any plotting function in `ggplot2`) only plot `x` and `y` as isolated vectors (not from a `data.frame`)?

```
   x <- rnorm(30)
   y <- rnorm(30)
   d <- data.frame(x, y)

  ggplot(d)+ geom_point(aes(x,y)) # I know this works but this requires `x` & `y` to be from a `data.frame`

 ## But is there a plotting function ggplot2 that would work just like:

 plot(y~x)  # using `x` and `y` directly without a `data.frame`
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check this. It is possible no need of `d`:

```
library(ggplot2)

#Data
x <- rnorm(30)
y <- rnorm(30)

#Plot
ggplot()+ geom_point(aes(x,y))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can pass vectors in `aes` :

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot() + geom_point(aes(x, y))
```